# Contents of DIV tag after adding Jquery

Tags: jquery

When i see page source i cant see contents of div tag added by Jquery.

**Here is the Code**

```
<input type="button" id="add">
<div id="parent">

... 
...

</div>
```

Here button id is clicked , some contents are fetched from myurl , then contents appended to the div [parent] , contents displayed on html page , but not displayed when i see page source .

```
<script>
$('#add').click(function() {    

    $.ajax({
            url : 'myurl'

            success: function(data) {

             $("#parent").append(data);

            }       
          });
    return false; 
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Following is the sample data comes from url, it is placed in div named parent.

```
<div id="dynamic1">
      <a herf="#" id="makeithide">

</div>
<script>
     $('#makeithide').click(function() {
     $('#dynamic1').hide("slow");
     });
</script>
```

I want to hide div dynamic at click event of link makeithide. 
How can i do this ?

Comment: What are you using to look at the source?

Comment: you could check the added contents from console

Comment: Then just hit F12, and you have the console open, and when developing anything web related it's good to know how everything works in the console, so just start exploring.

Answer (score 1):

Content added dynamically does'nt show up when using "view source", as it's not in the source code, you'll need to use the console to see the added elements (F12 in most browsers).

Comment: Thank you very much , And what if i want to perform some operations to that contents?

Comment: The content is there once you've added it, like any other content, it just does'nt show when using "view source" as that shows the actual source code without the elements that are added with javascript.

Comment: @Programmer checkout event delegations.

Comment: And as @Jai points out, you can only attach event handlers to elements that exists at the time you attach the event handlers, so sometimes event delegation is neccessary.

Comment: @adeneo and what if i want to process with elements added by javascript?

Comment: i want to hide dynamic div , which is added by Jquery